# Stellarium script star of bethlehem

Tags: star, planet

Does anyone out there have a script to replicate the star of Bethlehem.  In this case meaning a conjunction of Venus and Jupiter near Regulus.

Comment: Set the time to a Julian date of 1720550.70833.  It also helps to turn of atmosphere, as the conjunction occurs in the morning twilight.

Comment: Not in all timezones it doesn't.

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin What exactly did you mean 7 years ago?

Comment: I suspect I meant that you need to be aware that that precise Julian date isn’t morning twilight everywhere

Comment: Yes, actually from Bethlehem 1720550.59 is a better time for the morning twilight.

Answer (score 2):

I like sharing the following quote [from Wikipedia on the Star of Bethlehem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_Bethlehem)

> Astronomers have made several attempts to link the star to unusual celestial events, such as a conjunction of Jupiter and Saturn or Jupiter and Venus, a comet, or a supernova.
>
> Some modern scholars do not consider the story to be describing a historical event but a pious fiction created by the author of the Gospel of Matthew.

This said, luckily you specify that you are after a **conjunction of Jupiter and Venus**. [WolframAlpha can determine the conjunction of Venus and Jupiter closest to the year 0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=conjunction++venus+and+jupiter+0+BC):

> 8:07:26 pm LMT  |  Thursday, October 14, 2 BC (extrapolated Gregorian calendar)

I have never used Stellarium, but other software, where entering that date and searching for Jupiter did the job.

Comment: I am aware that this answer is in principle already in the comments, but I feel a bit of explanation does not hurt.